# Lambdas on AWS with CloudFormation error:"A version for this Lambda function exists. Modify the function to create a new version."

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm deploying an AWS lambda using CloudFormation.

In the template I use the flag `AutoPublishAlias: v1` which should create a version, add the necessary permissions, and update the alias "v1" to point to the latest version.

When I deploy this change, I get the following error:

```
A version for this Lambda function exists ( 8 ). Modify the function to create a new version.
```

I am using CICD.  Sometimes I redeploy the same lambda having modified another part of the CloudFormation template (e.g adding the `AutoPublishAlias` flag).

I thought CloudFormation was supposed to be able to handle this correctly - only updating resources which have changed?

So why am I seeing this error, and is there a workaround other than introducing a dummy code change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://seed.run/docs/serverless-errors/a-version-for-this-lambda-function-exists.html

The error is not Cloudformation, it's Serverless telling CF to deploy a new lambda version, which is in fact the same one.

I saw this issue after upgrading from sls 1 to 2. Had to do dummy changes for every function at once.

After that haven't seen the issue come up.

Comment: I have this issue even though im changing the function

Comment: This has nothing to do with Serverless. I'm using AWS CDK and seeing this issue.

Comment: fairpoint, cdk and serverless both generate cloudformation code where this error comes up. But the solution is essentially the same

Comment: I have seen this when the Code location for the function changes even though the code (hash) has not really changed (like using a different s3 prefix in a SAM deploy).